# Как получить xml с WebException?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Всем доброго времени суток!

Сайт при ошибке возвращает xml с описанием ошибки и ее кодом, если делать запрос в браузере. Если делать его из кода с помощью удобного класса `XDocument`, методом `Load(string)`, то упадет ошибка еще на стадии `GetResponse()`, вот что в тестах:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код такой:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("https://api.eveonline.com/char/AccountBalance.xml.aspx");

var element = document.Root;
var name = element?.Name;
Assert.IsTrue ( name != null && name == "eveapi" );
```

Вот какая ссылка была изначально: https://api.eveonline.com/char/AccountBalance.xml.aspx
Как мне обработать то что возвращает сайт?

Comment: Хм. А `XDocument`, по-вашему, не «готовая библиотека»?

Comment: @VladD, я имел ввиду библиотеки которые уже предоставляют модель данных с запросами к конкретному апи

Comment: Если сервер возвращает 400 на запрос, и прикрепляет к нему XML, вы так просто его не получите. Потому что команда `Load` ожидает 2xx, а всё остальное считает просто ошибкой, и игнорирует прикреплённый XML.

Comment: (Или может быть он где-то есть в свойствах исключения.)

Comment: В любом случае, покажите код.

Comment: @VladD, самый простой код, добавил в шапку

Comment: Как VladD и подозревал, этот xml можно получить из потока, возвращаемого методом `GetResponseStream` у WebException. Но всё же нужно отправлять правильный запрос с указанием UserID и парсить нормально полученный xml.

Comment: _можно ли десериализовать чужие xml в классы_ - да, можно. Однако, ваш вопрос слишком общий. Полагаю, его можно разделить на несколько. Один - как парсить xml, другой - как сделать правильный запрос.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, так и сделаю